# jQuery UI Accordion "jumps" on load

Tags: jquery, user-interface, accordion

I just finished a portfolio website for a college web design/graphic design course, and I am using the jQuery UI accordion for my part of my navigation. [My website is live, you can click here to see it.](http://www.brookecbenson.com)

If you click on "work," the accordion folds out, but you'll notice it does a little "jump" into place. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I've tried changing the autoHeight to false in the java script, which does nothing.

Here's a fiddle with my HTML and CSS, but I noticed it renders a jump in a different way than my live site.. http://jsfiddle.net/jNYAc/

The jQuery code I currently have is very simple:

```
$(function () {
    $(".accordion").accordion({
        active: false,
        collapsible: true
    });
});
```

If anyone has any suggestions, I would really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why this works, but if I add `overflow: hidden` to the container div (`<div class="nav">`), then the jump is gone. I also removed the `height` declaration.

My guess is that the div changes width when the accordion is open, and that forces the "jump" - and by adding `overflow:hidden`, the width doesn't matter as the UI just ignores the width of the `<ul>` inside it.

Note: I did this directly on your page in devtools, not the jsfiddle.

Comment: No problem, I'd just be careful that the `overflow:hidden` doesn't hide content from your inner content.